# "Widget Tree View" in Android Studio Editor?

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I'm using the most current version of Android Studio to develop Flutter Apps/Flutter 2.5.3.

In some projects, I can see the widget tree graphic lines in the editor, but sometimes when creating a new Flutter project it does not appear. And I'm unable to find the option to turn it on. Does anybody know the secret switch?
Thanks

Good editor settings: (see the yellow marked widget tree lines)
[image]

Bad editor settings: (no tree view... :-( )
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to "File/Settings," then search for "Flutter" and enable "Show UI Guides for build methods":

[image]

Comment: This didn't help in my case.

Comment: try to reload android studio